# Chapel: Can you re-index a domain in place?

Tags: chapel

A great man once said, I have a matrix `A`. But this time she has a friend `B`.  Like the Montagues and Capulets, they have different domains.

```
// A.domain is { 1..10, 1..10 }
// B.domain is { 0.. 9, 0.. 9 }

for ij in B.domain {
  if B[ij] <has a condition> {
    // poops
    A[ij] = B[ij];
  }
}
```

My guess is I need to reindex so that the `B.domain` is `{1..10, 1..10}`.  Since B is an input, I get push back from the compiler. Any suggestions?

Comment: @user3666197 is correct about your example being invalid Chapel code, due to assigning domains of arrays like `A.domain`.. It might be worth updating it to avoid confusion in the future -- My answer took an educated guess at what you intended to do.

Comment: Ben, feel free to modify the syntax. Just tried to sketch an idea to approach the solution from a pure and cheap index-translation so as to avoid any large-scale ( as Brian is keen to often add ) **`.reindex()`** or any even more expensive memory-mapping / memory-dupes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a [`reindex`](http://chapel.cray.com/docs/master/builtins/internal/ChapelArray.html#ChapelArray.reindex) array method to accomplish exactly this, and you can create a `ref` to the result to prevent creating a new array:

```
var Adom = {1..10,1..10},
    Bdom = {0..9, 0..9};

var A: [Adom] real,
    B: [Bdom] real;

// Set B to 1.0
B = 1;

// 0-based reference to A -- note that Bdom must be same shape as Adom
ref A0 = A.reindex(Bdom);

// Set all of A's values to B's values
for ij in B.domain {
  A0[ij] = B[ij];
}

// Confirm A is now 1.0 now
writeln(A);
```

Answer (score 0):

### [chapel](/questions/tagged/chapel) compiler must object,
documentation is explicit and clear on this:

> Note that querying an array's domain via the **`.domain`** method or the function argument query syntax does **not** result in a domain expression that can be reassigned. In particular, **we cannot do:**
>
> **`VarArr.domain = {1..2*n};`**

In case the **`<has_a_condition>`** is non-intervening and without side-effects, a solution to the expressed will may use domain-operators similar to this pure, contiguous-domain, index translation:

```
forall ij in B.domain do {
   if <has_a_condition> {
      A[ ij(1) + A.domain.dims()(1).low,
         ij(2) + A.domain.dims()(2).low
         ] = B[ij];
   }
}
```

Comment: I understand the syntax, I'm just conveying the ideas.

Comment: Interesting are the hopefully just [PTIME] and [PSPACE] costs of the Ben's approach, vs. a [CTIME] ( lim -> 0, if compiler gets the CPU-registers to service properly ) and [CSPACE] == 0 approach here. For MAD/Massive Matrix A, B manipulations, this is out of question an aspect to carefully check.